# Do we Desire out of Hope or we Hope out of Desire?

Tags: existence, existentialism

Just for an example consider the following specific scenerio:

If I desire that I want a million dollars in few years, is that out of hope of better future.

OR

I hope of a better future, because I am desiring a million dollars in near future.

But thinking in terms of general scenarios in our life answer the question:

Considering the standard dictionary definitions, what is the primal force, Hope or Desire?

Comment: Why does one have to be more basic than the other?

Comment: @Canyon IMO they are not independent. One must preceed the other.

Comment: They're certainly not independent, but why does one have to precede the other?

Comment: @Canyon i dont know....may be you can provide an answer why they are on the same level of something also i dont know.

Comment: Vague questions such as yours that are prone to inviting personal opinions are not really suitable for our format, we take more pointed questions that are more or less objectively answerable based on existing literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some quick dictionary definitions:

**Desire**: a strong feeling of wanting something or wishing for something to happen

**Hope**: a feeling of expectation and desire for something to happen

The key difference seems to be that hope is desire AND expectation. Hope appears to include a sense of moving *towards* what one desires (whether by our own will or effort, by luck or some external force). Desire without hope, on the other hand, can lead to despair or anger.

One can desire a million dollars for reasons other than hope for a better future, and can hope for a better future by desiring something other than a million dollars.

The connection created between hoping for a better future and desiring a million dollars, then, is an arbitrary one. The primal force here is not necessarily hope or desire, but perhaps **fear** that the only way to a *better* future is *with* a million dollars.

I desire a million dollars and I also hope for it whenever I check my lottery ticket - but I'm under no illusions that it will necessarily lead to a *better* future.

Likewise I desire a better future and I hope for it when I get up to go to work each morning, when I make decisions about my future (including paying for a lottery ticket), and whenever I strive to teach my children or otherwise make an impact on the world around me. I understand that there are many ways to a better future.